# Windows 7 does not refresh dvd/cd player contents

Tags: windows-7, notifications, autoplay

First of all, let me start by saying that I don't think that this is an auto-play problem.

When I put a music CD into my cd/dvd drive, nothing happens.  If I have an explorer windows open it does not show a change in the CD drive at all.

I can wait minutes and still nothing happens.

In the explorer window, if I then press F5, the window refreshes, the CD shows it contains an audio CD and the music starts (I have the auto play option set to play for audio CDs)

Exact same behavior with DVD and games CDs

So, it looks like some type of Insert notification is not happening.

Any ideas?

**CONFIGURATION:**
Windows 7 Ultimate 64, sp1; Pioneer 219L CD/DVD player

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only thing I can suggest it to open device manager, expand the DVD/CD-ROM drives, right click on your problem drive and select "uninstall", close DM and reboot, windows will reinstall the drive and its drivers, see if this helps the issue.

2 ways to open DM, on the start menu right click on "Computer" and select 
manage", when it opens select device manager on the left side.

or

Control Panel (icon view) > Device Manager

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, already tried this with no effect

Comment: If you can install a different dvd drive, see if the behavior is the same, or see if there is a "firmware" update for the pioneer drive.

Comment: bizarre, it works when I swap out the drive for an older drive.  However there is no firmware update available for the 219L

Comment: Try it in another PC if you can, if it behaves the same way, its time for an upgrade.